# How does gender status impact access to political resources?

Tags: political-system, canada, gender

I am currently taking a course in male and female relationships and I was wondering how gender impacts the access to political resources or if there is a "gender lens" (male or female) in politics in Canada?

For example, are men more favourable when applying for a job in politics compared to a women or are men taken more seriously rather than females?
(Will the interviewer when apply for a job consider a male over a female even though they both have the same level of eduction/knowledge/experience)

I am curious if there are situations in politics where a male or a female cannot achieve something because of their gender or if they are treated differently.

Comment: Adding more questions is unlikely to help.  That makes the question Too Broad.  Consider instead clarifying what it would mean for men to be more favorable when applying for a job in politics.  More likely to be hired?  As a percentage of applicants?  Or what?

Comment: Please define your usage of *"gender status"*.  It's unclear if this means the same thing as *"gender"* alone, or locale-based ranking systems, or something else...

Comment: Just pointing out, a difference in outcome is not necessarily because of a difference in treatment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure.

For example, the position of Minister of Status of Women (previously the Minister responsible for the Status of Women) was created in 1971, and has been held exclusively by women since September 22, 1981 (but not at all prior to that.)

The Minister of Finance, on the other hand, has been around since the beginning, and has always been held by a man.

This could be coincidence, or a matter of "access to political resources", or something else.

The most straightforward example prior to 2013 may have been the agnatic primogeniture order of succession for the Canadian monarchy, but the Succession to the Throne Act of 2013 amended the Canadian Constitution to switch to absolute primogeniture.